# Jenkins Android Emulator Plugin startup process is 'stopped'

Tags: jenkins, android-emulator, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins Android Emulator Plugin.
but the emulator startup process seems to stopped.
This is the build log

```
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building on master in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/em
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android list target
[android] Using Android SDK: /opt/android-sdk-linux
[android] Creating Android AVD: /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86.avd
[android] /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android create avd -f -a -c 64M -s WVGA800 -n hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86 -t android-23 --abi x86
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now at tcp:5833 *
* daemon started successfully *
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb start-server
[android] Starting Android emulator
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator -engine classic -ports 5794,5795 -report-console tcp:5828,max=60 -prop persist.sys.language=en -prop persist.sys.country=US -avd hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86 -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -wipe-data -no-window -verbose -noaudio -no-boot-anim
WARNING: Force to use classic engine to support snapshot.
emulator: Android virtual device file at: /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86.ini
emulator: virtual device content at /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86.avd
emulator: virtual device config file: /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86.avd/config.ini
emulator: using core hw config path: /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Found AVD target API level: 23
emulator: Read property file at /opt/android-sdk-linux/system-images/android-23/default/x86//build.prop
emulator: No boot.prop property file found.
emulator: found skin 'WVGA800' in directory: /opt/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-23/skins/
emulator: autoconfig: -skin WVGA800
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir /opt/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-23/skins/
emulator: found skin-specific hardware.ini: /opt/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-23/skins//WVGA800/hardware.ini
emulator: autoconfig: -kernel /opt/android-sdk-linux/system-images/android-23/default/x86//kernel-qemu
emulator: Target arch = 'x86'
emulator: Auto-config: -qemu -cpu qemu32
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel image requires legacy device naming scheme.
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk /opt/android-sdk-linux/system-images/android-23/default/x86//ramdisk.img
emulator: Using initial system image: /opt/android-sdk-linux/system-images/android-23/default/x86//system.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86.avd/cache.img
emulator: autoconfig: -sdcard /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86.avd/sdcard.img
emulator: Increasing RAM size to 1024MB
emulator: VM heap size 48MB is below hardware specified minimum of 192MB,setting it to that value
emulator: System image is read only
emulator: autoconfig: -snapstorage /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86.avd/snapshots.img
emulator: GPU emulation is disabled
emulator: Found 2 DNS servers: 8.8.8.8 168.95.192.1
emulator: trying to load skin file '/opt/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-23/skins//WVGA800/layout'
emulator: Found 2 DNS servers: 8.8.8.8 168.95.192.1
emulator: WARNING: Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored.
Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = x86
  hw.cpu.model = qemu32
  hw.cpu.ncore = 2
  hw.ramSize = 1024
  hw.screen = multi-touch
  hw.mainKeys = true
  hw.trackBall = true
  hw.keyboard = false
  hw.keyboard.lid = false
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = true
  hw.gsmModem = true
  hw.gps = true
  hw.battery = true
  hw.accelerometer = true
  hw.audioInput = true
  hw.audioOutput = true
  hw.sdCard = true
  hw.sdCard.path = /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86.avd/sdcard.img
  disk.cachePartition = true
  disk.cachePartition.path = /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86.avd/cache.img
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  hw.lcd.width = 480
  hw.lcd.height = 800
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 160
  hw.lcd.backlight = true
  hw.gpu.enabled = false
  hw.gpu.mode = (null)
  hw.gpu.blacklisted = no
  hw.initialOrientation = portrait
  hw.camera.back = emulated
  hw.camera.front = none
  vm.heapSize = 192
  hw.sensors.light = true
  hw.sensors.pressure = true
  hw.sensors.humidity = true
  hw.sensors.proximity = true
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = true
  hw.sensors.orientation = true
  hw.sensors.temperature = true
  hw.useext4 = true
  kernel.path = /opt/android-sdk-linux/system-images/android-23/default/x86//kernel-qemu
  kernel.newDeviceNaming = no
  kernel.supportsYaffs2 = no
  disk.ramdisk.path = /opt/android-sdk-linux/system-images/android-23/default/x86//ramdisk.img
  disk.systemPartition.initPath = /opt/android-sdk-linux/system-images/android-23/default/x86//system.img
  disk.systemPartition.size = 1280m
  disk.dataPartition.path = /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86.avd/userdata-qemu.img
  disk.dataPartition.initPath = /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86.avd/userdata.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 2g
  disk.snapStorage.path = /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86.avd/snapshots.img
  avd.name = hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86
.
emulator: CPU Acceleration: working
emulator: CPU Acceleration status: KVM (version 12) is installed and usable.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator64-x86"
emulator: argv[01] = "-audio"
emulator: argv[02] = "none"
emulator: argv[03] = "-dns-server"
emulator: argv[04] = "8.8.8.8,168.95.192.1"
emulator: argv[05] = "-serial"
emulator: argv[06] = "null"
emulator: argv[07] = "-serial"
emulator: argv[08] = "null"
emulator: argv[09] = "-boot-property"
emulator: argv[10] = "persist.sys.language=en"
emulator: argv[11] = "-boot-property"
emulator: argv[12] = "persist.sys.country=US"
emulator: argv[13] = "-android-ports"
emulator: argv[14] = "5794,5795"
emulator: argv[15] = "-android-report-console"
emulator: argv[16] = "tcp:5828,max=60"
emulator: argv[17] = "-enable-kvm"
emulator: argv[18] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[19] = "/var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
emulator: argv[20] = "-append"
emulator: argv[21] = "qemu=1 androidboot.hardware=goldfish clocksource=pit android.qemud=1 console=0 console=0 android.checkjni=1 android.bootanim=0 qemu.gles=0 ndns=2"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator64-x86 -audio none -dns-server 8.8.8.8,168.95.192.1 -serial null -serial null -boot-property persist.sys.language=en -boot-property persist.sys.country=US -android-ports 5794,5795 -android-report-console tcp:5828,max=60 -enable-kvm -android-hw /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86.avd/hardware-qemu.ini -append 'qemu=1 androidboot.hardware=goldfish clocksource=pit android.qemud=1 console=0 console=0 android.checkjni=1 android.bootanim=0 qemu.gles=0 ndns=2'
emulator: Starting QEMU main loop
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Using kernel serial device prefix: ttyS
emulator: AVD Name: hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86
emulator: Ramdisk image contains fstab.goldfish file
emulator: Found format of system partition: 'ext4'
emulator: Found format of userdata partition: 'ext4'
emulator: Found format of cache partition: 'ext4'
emulator: system partition format: ext4
emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0x50000000,file=/opt/android-sdk-linux/system-images/android-23/default/x86//system.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0,readonly
emulator: userdata partition format: ext4
emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0x80000000,file=/var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86.avd/userdata-qemu.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: cache partition format: ext4
emulator: Creating empty cache partition image at: /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86.avd/cache.img
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000,file=/var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-23_x86.avd/cache.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '192m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '160'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '1'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'back'
emulator: Found 2 DNS servers: 8.8.8.8 168.95.192.1
emulator: Kernel parameters: qemu=1 androidboot.hardware=goldfish clocksource=pit android.qemud=1 console=0 console=0 android.checkjni=1 android.bootanim=0 qemu.gles=0 ndns=2
emulator:     trying to find: /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/bios.bin

emulator:     trying to find: /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/pc-bios/bios.bin

emulator:     trying to find: /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/vgabios-cirrus.bin

emulator:     trying to find: /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/pc-bios/vgabios-cirrus.bin

emulator: Adding boot property: 'persist.sys.language' = 'en'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'persist.sys.country' = 'US'
emulator: (android_emulation_setup) using custom adb server port 5833
emulator: ro.adb.qemud invalid or not found, API >= 16, defaulting ro.adb.qemud = 0
emulator: (setup_console_and_adb_ports) trying console port 5794, adb port 5795 (legacy: true)
emulator: (android_console_start) initializing on port 5794
emulator: sent '0012host:emulator:5795' to ADB server
emulator: WARNING: Requested adb port (5795) is outside the recommended range [5555,5586]. ADB may not function properly for the emulator. See -help-port for details.
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5794
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5794
emulator: trying to find console-report client on tcp:5828
emulator: console port number sent to remote. resuming boot
[android] Emulator reported that the console is available on port 5,794
[android] Waiting for emulator to finish booting...
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5794 wait-for-device shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
emulator: android_hw_fingerprint_init: fingerprint qemud listen service initialized

emulator: Skipping metrics reporting: No user opt-in.
emulator: _hwFingerprint_connect: connect finger print listen is called

emulator: got message from guest system fingerprint HAL

[android] Emulator reported that the startup process is 'running'
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5794 wait-for-device shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
[android] Emulator reported that the startup process is 'stopped'
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5794 logcat -v time
[android] Emulator is ready for use (took 49 seconds)
```

At the end of the log

```
[android] Emulator reported that the startup process is 'stopped'
```

But after I took a long while to build, the emulator miraculously success. The Build log would have:

```
Your emulator is out of date, please update by launching Android Studio:
 - Start Android Studio
 - Select menu "Tools > Android > SDK Manager"
 - Click "SDK Tools" tab
 - Check "Android SDK Tools" checkbox
 - Click "OK"
```

I know the emulator is success because I run gradle **connectedDebugAndroidTest** after the emulator start up.

This is my emulator setup snapshot
[image]

and with the -noaudio -verbose options

I have tried to run the same emulator on shell script, and it work perfectly.

My Android-Emulator plugin version is 2.15

Thanks for helping